# incomplete line in the rprofile.site

Tags: r, tinn-r

When I send command from Tinn-R to R by hotkey, sometimes this error shows up:

```
Error in source(.trPaths[5], echo = TRUE, max.deparse.length = 150) : 
  object '.trPaths' not found
```

But If I copy and paste the same command into R manually, no error message at all.

Then I tried:

```
> grep(".trPaths",readLines(file.path(R.home(component="etc"),"Rprofile.site")))>0
```

and the message was:

```
In readLines(file.path(R.home(component = "etc"), "Rprofile.site")) :
  incomplete final line found on 'D:/Programs/R-3.1.1/etc/Rprofile.site'
```

I did make a change to the `rprofile.site` by adding a line setting up my working directory.

Any suggestion what I should do?

Thanks.

Comment: To not get the "incomplete final line" warning, you can specify `warn=FALSE` or you can open the Rprofile.site file.  Go to the last line, and hit enter.  Save the file.

Comment: Hi Gsee, thank you. the final line is complete by hitting ENTER/SAVE.                        But R-send in tinn-r still refuses to work, left me the same error message~